# Godot and HID devices

Tags: serial-port, usb, godot

I have HID device in my ports they acts like a touch input in my godot game. I want to connect another HID device in other port. want to read the data on the selected usb port, for example I want to read only port 1 or port2 how can I do this ?

Comment: In Godot input events do not specify from which device they are from. For joypads you can read them by a device index, however I don't see a way to do it for mouse or touch. You might have to look into integrating a native library with Godot via module or GDExtension.